# How to loop multiple XML file in visual basic?

Tags: xml, vb.net, loops

I was trying to loop the data in multiple xml file.

```
Dim streamReader As StreamReader
        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        Dim classificationFiles As New List(Of String)
        classificationFiles.Add("classifications.xml")
        classificationFiles.Add("classifications2.xml")

        Try
            For Each classificationXML In classificationFiles
                streamReader = New StreamReader(classificationXML)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            frmMain.txtInfo.AppendText(vbCrLf + "unable to open 'classifications.xml', error: ")
            frmMain.txtInfo.AppendText(ex.Message + vbCrLf)
            Return False
        End Try
```

This are my code, it does work but it only read the latest file only which is data in (classifications2.xml).

Comment: You're not using the contents of streamReader after opening the 1st file, so naturally after the loop exited, streamReader holds the contents of the last file.

Comment: The xml contain of the license plate training file, 1 xml file is not enough reference. But when I put in 2 xml file, it only run the second xml file for reference

Comment: Your code shows where you open the `StreamReader`, but where do you actually read the file?  You need to move that code into the `For Next` loop as indicated by the comment by HelO'Ween.